# how can i have a static ip address for my laptop which uses my mobile's hotspot for internet?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, ip, ip-address

I have been using mobile hotspot for internet on my laptop but now I am about to start a work which requires me to work with only one IP address that is a static IP address,basically, it is online form filling job which is to be done online from home,  they will give me login id and password of their site where I will be filling the forms,I guess because of this remote freelancing nature of the job they are asking me for a static ip address.

Comment: What do you mean your employer requires one IP address? They require you to have a STATIC PUBLIC IP address? Generally, mobile carriers do not provide that service. It is unusual for a employer to have this requirement, unless they are providing your service... I would talk to their IT department about using a client based VPN to connect to their network, then your IP address is not relevant, this is a much more common solution. Typically a static IP address is only required if your employer is doing a site to site based VPN and providing hardware for that connection to a physical interface.

Comment: @nish - can you elaborate as to why you need a fixed IP, and how you will be working? (Home / remote / etc)

Comment: @acejavelin it is online form filling job which is to be done online from home, basically, they will give me log in id and password of their site where I will be filling the forms, kind of freelancing

Comment: So they are just going to whitelist your IP address in an ACL or something? Not a very effective way to implement this in today's world. I would again see about a corporate VPN connection or something similar that is an acceptable solution to your employer.

Comment: hey, @acejavelin will VPN app on my mobile phone whose hotspot I am using or VPN extension in my laptop's browser in which i am using the hotspot to fill the forms will work?

Comment: I don't know enough about commercial VPN services to answer this question. If the connection can give a static IP address, then it will likely work, if not, it probably won't make any difference.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to contact your wireless service provider. IP addresses are handed out by them, according to their settings, and you'll need to see if a static IP address is an option, and it'll probably cost more money.

An alternative is to use a VPN, where your internet connection's IP address doesn't matter as much, and the VPN can certainly be set up to have a static IP address.